# upgrading ssis 2008 c# architecture to 2016 for azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, ssis-2008, biml, ssis-2016

i m trying to upgrade ssis 2008 packages with c# architecture (screenshot joined), to ssis 2016 for moving to the cloud, i ve seen similar questions but the few answers there are do not apply when i try them, especially not this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15 the wizard dont list my 2008 packages when i run it, after importing em on a new 2016 solution, and it doen trun automatically,

[image]

do you have a tested way to upgrade 2008 packages with the above format?

currently i m trying bimlStudio, seems to be a lead, didn t figure it out yet,

thank you,

Comment: You have SSIS packages sitting in a C# project. That's your first issue

Comment: Yes that is an issue, i m trying to download ssdt 2008 to add the existing dtsx packages to the 2008 ssis solution, and then try to run the upgrade wizard on 2016, that s the primitive idea i have for now

Comment: The bits for SSIS package editing in 2005 and 2008, then called Business Intelligence Designer Studio (BIDS), are on the ISO that SQL Server itself is stamped on. There is no facility to download the BIDS tooling. With SQL Server 2012+, the bits were renamed as SQL Server Data Tools - BI Edition (SSDT-BI) and then later, just SSDT. That's freely available as a download/extension to Visual Studio.